# Drag from Tree to div

Tags: drag-and-drop, extjs

I am trying to implement a drag and drop senario from an extJs TreePanel into a div in the body of the page. I have been following an example by Saki [here](http://examples.extjs.eu/).

So far I have the below code:

```
var contentAreas = new Array();
var tree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
                title : 'Widgets',
                useArrows: true,
                autoScroll: true,
                animate: true,
                enableDrag: true,
                border: false,
                layout:'fit',
                ddGroup:'t2div',
                loader:new Ext.tree.TreeLoader(),
                root:new Ext.tree.AsyncTreeNode({
                    expanded:true,
                    leaf:false,
                    text:'Tree Root',
                    children:children
                }),
                listeners:{
                    startdrag:function() {
                         $('.content-area').css("outline", "5px solid #FFE767");
                    },
                    enddrag:function() {
                        $('.content-area').css("outline", "0");
                    }
                }
            });

            var areaDivs = Ext.select('.content-area', true);
            Ext.each(areaDivs, function(el) {
                var dd = new Ext.dd.DropTarget(el, {
                    ddGroup:'t2div',
                    notifyDrop:function(ddt, e, node) {
                        alert('Drop');
                        return true;
                    } 
                });
                contentAreas[contentAreas.length] = dd;
            });
```

The drag begins and the div highlights but when I get over the div it does not show as a valid drop target and the drop fails.

This is my first foray into extJS. I'm  JQuery through and through and I am struggling at the moment.

Any help would be appreciated.

Ian

**Edit**

Furthermore if I create a panel with a drop target in it, this works fine. What is the difference between creating an element and selecting an existing element from the dom. This is obviously where I am going wrong but I'm none the wiser. I have to be able to select existing dom elements and make them into drop targets so the code below is not an option.

Here is the drop target that works

```
var target = new Ext.Panel({
                renderTo: document.body
                ,layout:'fit'
                ,id:'target'
                ,bodyStyle:'font-size:13px'
                ,title:'Drop Target'
                ,html:'<div class="drop-target" '
                      +'style="border:1px silver solid;margin:20px;padding:8px;height:140px">'
                      +'Drop a node here. I\'m the DropTarget.</div>'

                // setup drop target after we're rendered
                ,afterRender:function() {
                    Ext.Panel.prototype.afterRender.apply(this, arguments);
                    this.dropTarget = this.body.child('div.drop-target');
                    var dd = new Ext.dd.DropTarget(this.dropTarget, {
                        // must be same as for tree
                         ddGroup:'t2div'

                        // what to do when user drops a node here
                        ,notifyDrop:function(dd, e, node) {
                            alert('drop');
                            return true;
                        } // eo function notifyDrop
                    });
                } 
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if adding `true` as the second param here makes any difference:

```
var areaDivs = Ext.select('.content-area', true);
```

As a cosmetic note, the param name `e` conventionally indicates an event object (as in the second arg of `notifyDrop`).  For an element, `el` is more typical.  Doesn't matter functionally, but looks weird to someone used to Ext code to see `e` passed into the DropTarget constructor.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't seem to have made any difference. This would be so easy in JQuery! So the drop targets are being created and stored in the contentAreas array correctly. But the drop is not valid even thought the group is the same. Is there a function that decides if a drop is valid that I can override maybe? Any ideas?

Comment: Your code looks OK at a glance.  Sometimes using CompositeElements/flyweight objects (as opposed to full Elements with the true arg) does not work as expected for stuff like this, but that was just a guess.  If you can show a sample of your HTML I bet I could solve it for you pretty easily.  Most likely either your select is not returning valid elements or the DropTargets are not being initialized correctly with those elements for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problem duplicating a working example such as that, copy the entire thing, then modify it to your needs line-by-line - you can't go wrong.

Comment: That's basically what I did but making the final change to allow the div not to be created by extJs was what broke it and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

As i know you can't set DropZone to any Ext element, just to Ext component. So this might be you problem. Try to use DropTarget instead of DropZone.

Comment: This should be comment not answer.